# Getting indices of elements that are in another list in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays and I'd like to get the indices of all elements in the first array that are in the second array. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5])
y = np.array([1,3])
# want to get np.array([1,2,4])
```

If `y` were a scalar, I could just do `np.where(x == y)`. Is there an equivalent for arrays of values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(x, y))
(array([1, 2, 4]),)
```